# AS3 - sort arraycollection alpha numeric values

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

i'm trying to sort an arraycollection that uses letters and numbers

Currently I'm getting "b12,c1,b1,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b0,b13,b14,b15" but want "b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,c1"

Please can anyone suggest when're I have gone wrong?

```
var dataSortField:SortField = new SortField();
    dataSortField.name = "order";
    dataSortField.numeric = false;
    dataSortField.compareFunction = sortAlphaNumeric;
var numericDataSort:Sort = new Sort();
    numericDataSort.fields = [dataSortField];
pageArrCol.sort = numericDataSort;

private function sortAlphaNumeric(a:String, b:String):int {
    var reA:RegExp = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    var reN:RegExp = /[^0-9]/g;
    var aA:String = a.replace(reA,"");
    var bA:String = b.replace(reA,"");
    if (aA === bA) {
        var aN:int = parseInt(a.replace(reN,""),10);
        var bN:int = parseInt(b.replace(reN,""),10);
        return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the results you expect?  What are the results you are seeing?  How exactly are zero's a problem?

Comment: Hi, i've just edited the question

Comment: What are you starting with?  What is your thought behind the sortAlphaNumeric function?  Can you assume a constant / consistent string structure of 'letter' + 'number'?

Comment: i'm adding numbered pages but starting with a letter a,b or c then the number of the page - relative to the letter so grouping the a's, b's and c's.  There won't be any other letter values and they will always follow with a number

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that b12,c1,b1 is your input format

You may have meant, a.match(regex)[0]

```
var reA:RegExp = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;
var reN:RegExp = /[0-9]+/g;

var aA:String = a.match(reA)[0];
var bA:String = b.match(reA)[0];

if (aA === bA) {
    var aN:int = parseInt(a.match(reN)[0],10);
    var bN:int = parseInt(b.match(reN)[0],10);
    return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
}else {
    return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I have not tested this, but you should not be using replace, use match instead. Also, the regular expression is wrong. You have to revisit the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks but what would I return in the else bracket below?

Comment: else block would be the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
myArrayCollectionToSort.source.sortOn("order", sortAlphaNumeric);

private function sortAlphaNumeric(a:String, b:String):int {
    var reA:RegExp = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g;
    var reN:RegExp = /[^0-9]+/g;
    var aA:String = a.match(reA)[0];
    var bA:String = b.match(reA)[0];
    if (aA == bA) {
         var aN:int = parseInt(a.match(reN)[0],10);
         var bN:int = parseInt(b.match(reN)[0],10);
         return aN == bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I don't test it but it should works, and array is way faster than an ArrayCollection. (arraycollection.source is an array). If the sorted ArrayCollection is binded you need to dispatch a refresh event if you want the bind to works:

```
myArrayCollectionToSort.dispatchEvent(new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, false, false, CollectionEventKind.REFRESH));
```

or

```
myArrayCollectionToSort.refresh();
```